# Replace text that only contain specific characters Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have text in following formats:

```
ASP1618099.jpg
ASP1618100.jpg
ASP1618101.jpg
```

and need to change them with:

```
ASP1717099.jpg
ASP1717100.jpg
ASP1717101.jpg
```

It can be replaced with simply but the problem is that the file has multiple entries with same name and only extension is change like:

```
ASP1618099.png
ASP1618100.png
ASP1618101.png
```

Now I only want to change text with the extension of .jpg and do not want to change text having extension .png.

Comment: What are the rules for the replacements being done here?

Answer (score 2):

Find:

```
 ^ASP1618(\d{3})(?=.jpg)
```

Repl:

```
ASP1717${1}
```

Search mode: Regular expression